# Sync kafka producer send still got 0 secs timeout?

Tags: python, apache-kafka

I have the following code in a Python script

```
from kafka import KafkaProducer

kafka_producer = KafkaProducer(....)

kafka_producer.send(topic, value=message)
kafka_producer.flush()

logger.info('Done!') # this message is displayed
```

However, I still saw the following messsage. It seems the message was sent successfully. Why the message of "0 secs timeout" is displayed even if `flush()` is called?

> INFO:root:Done!

> INFO:kafka.producer.kafka:Closing the Kafka producer with 0 secs timeout.

> INFO:kafka.producer.kafka:Proceeding to force close the producer since pending requests could not be completed within timeout 0.

> INFO:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=2 host=....  [IPv4('....', 9092)]>: Closing connection.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error message is incorrect in this case. The relevant code - [source on github](https://github.com/dpkp/kafka-python/blob/e4913db244ca4d435d279d3047aef3c1c01ebd51/kafka/producer/kafka.py#L485)

```
        if timeout > 0:
            if invoked_from_callback:
                log.warning("Overriding close timeout %s secs to 0 in order to"
                            " prevent useless blocking due to self-join. This"
                            " means you have incorrectly invoked close with a"
                            " non-zero timeout from the producer call-back.",
                            timeout)
            else:
                # Try to close gracefully.
                if self._sender is not None:
                    self._sender.initiate_close()
                    self._sender.join(timeout)

        if self._sender is not None and self._sender.is_alive():
            log.info("Proceeding to force close the producer since pending"
                     " requests could not be completed within timeout %s.",
                     timeout)
            self._sender.force_close()
```

My interpretation of the code:
If `timeout` is `0` we skip the graceful close code and go straight to the force close. The only conditions checked on the `_sender` before logging are that it exists, and that it [is_alive()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.is_alive). Of course is exists, and it is alive because it was never told to close yet.

It never checks to see if anything could or couldn't be completed if the `timeout` is `0`. So the logging is incorrect in that case.

In the case where `timeout > 0` then the logging makes sense. `initiate_close()` gets called, as does [join()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join) which says you can only know if join was successful by checking `is_alive()` later. If it is still alive after the attempted `join()` then it is force closing it and requests couldn't be completed within the timeout.